# What is AWS S3 dataset?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-data-wrangler

Looking at documentation of [`awswrangler.s3.to_csv`](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#awswrangler-s3-to-csv) or [`awswrangler.s3.to_parquet`](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/2.17.0/stubs/awswrangler.s3.to_parquet.html#awswrangler-s3-to-parquet), there is a `dataset` parameter.

From testing, it looks like setting `dataset=True` allows, among other things, to append new data to an already existing set. It also looks like when `dataset=True`, I can't specify the file name and AWS autogenerates the names for the files which are added to the specified `path`.

Apart from that, I can't find more information on what `dataset` means. Is it just referring to the general concept or is there a specific meaning within the context of AWS? What exactly is `dataset` and when should it be set to `True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataset=True` option allows you to store the entire dataset, including all metadata, indexes, etc.

The `dataset` parameter [documentation](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.to_csv.html#awswrangler-s3-to-csv):

> **dataset** (bool) – If True store as a dataset instead of ordinary file(s) If True, enable all follow arguments: partition_cols, mode, database, table, description, parameters, columns_comments, concurrent_partitioning, catalog_versioning, projection_enabled, projection_types, projection_ranges, projection_values, projection_intervals, projection_digits, catalog_id, schema_evolution.

Note all those extra things that get saved when you save a dataset. All that information, like `columns_comments`, `concurrent_partitioning`, `projection_values`, will be lost when you save to CSV or Parquet. But on the other hand, those values are probably only useful if you plan to do further manipulation of the data via awswrangler/pandas at some later date.

Also note that if you set `dataset=True` you have to give it a file name prefix instead of a single file name, because the output generated will be spread across multiple files.

If you want to use the data in any other tool besides Pandas, such as loading the CSV into Excel, then you most likely want to set `dataset=False` and output to a single file.